# Bootstrap - column overlay

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my view I display a PDF with a pane that floats to the left side to show tags of the PDF. The space contains a table with a row for each tag. I want the table to stay within the column (responsively) independent of the content in the columns of the table. The problem is that when browser width reduces, the column with the PDF will float over the column with the pane.

Update: not sure if relevant, yet I use Rails 5.

The app uses vanilla bootstrap and this is my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div data-spy="affix">
            <%= simple_form_for([@annotation, @annotation.tags.build], html: { class: 'form-vertical', multipart: true }) do |f| %>
                <%= f.button :submit, 'Add tag' %>
                <%= link_to 'Close', annotation_path(@annotation), :class => "btn btn-default" %>
                <%= link_to 'List' , annotations_path, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
                <br><br>
                    <%= f.error_notification %>
                    <%= f.input :content, placeholder: 'Annotated content', label: false %>
                    <%= f.input :location, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => 'x=0, y=0' }, label: false %>
                    <%= f.association :tagtype, prompt: 'Select tag type', label: false %>
            <% end -%>
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="annotationResults">
                <table id="tags" class="table table-hover" style="background-color: white; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 0.9em;" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Content tagged</th>
                            <th>as</th>
                            <th>in</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <% @annotation.tags.each do |tag| %>
                            <% unless tag.content.blank? %>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><%= tag.content %></td>
                                <td><%= tag.tagtype.name %></td>
                                <td><%= tag.tagtype.typeoftag %></td>
                                <td><%= link_to '', [tag.annotation, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% end -%>
                        <% end -%>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8" id="file">
        <%= content_tag :iframe, nil, src: pdf_annotation_path(@annotation), width: "100%", height: "875px", frameBorder: "0" %>
    </div>

</div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have a row and a container inside a column? That's not recommended, if you want part of the data below another part put it in a completely different row (there only should be a need for one container per page). I imagine part of your problem is to do with that. So try container->(row->column, column), (row, column). If that doesn't work then could you put it in a fiddle or bootply?

Comment: where do I have a container in a column please? I have container-fluid > row > col-md-4 > row > row.

Comment: Well you have it inside a row which is inside a column. Basically the padding is going to get messed up, you shouldn't need to have a row or a container inside a column or a container inside a row. For bootstrap to work as it's intended you should have a container (or container-fluid, same thing in this context), a row and then columns (which add up to 12 or have an offset and a column which adds up to 12).

Comment: tx, understood; have remove those (simplified the html so good :) ) - however, issue remains. New html in the question.

Comment: Oh, should've picked this up straight away (the other issue just got in my head). If you want a column to remain responsive for all displays you'll have to use `xs` in the column instead of `md`. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: nope - tried that - makes no difference.